# changing height of bar charts from new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, bar-chart

I have a bar chart made for the following array of objects

```
var data = [{"state":"California", "values":50},{"state":"Massachusetts":"values:20},{"state":"Texas", "values":15},{"state":"New York","values":5},{"state":"Washington", "values":1}]

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return barX(d.state); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return barY(+d.values); })
    .attr("width", barX.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", function(d) { return barH - barY(+d.values); })
```

The y-axis are the values and x-values are the states. The bar chart is in the order of the largest value to lowest value in the order as above. (CA, MA, TX, NY, WA) Now I have a new data set that looks like:

```
var data2 = [{"state":"Massachusetts","values":70},{"state":"California", "values":40},{"state":"New York","values":20},{"state":"Washington","values":15},{"state":"Texas", "values":10}]
```

I want the order of the bars to still be CA, MA, TX, NY, WA with their updated value of 40, 70, 10, 20, 15. My attempt now is changing the first bar (California) which is supposed to be a value of 40 to 70. I want to keep the ordering the same as the first data set. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your question is actually *"how to update the bars while keeping the order of the first render"*.

Well, that's actually simpler than it seems. You just need to define the order of the bars in your x scale the first time you render them (here, `data1` is your first data array):

```
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([foo, bar])
    .domain(data1.map(d => d.state))
```

And do not change that order anymore. Besides that, set a key function when binding the data:

```
.data(data, d => d.state)
```

Here is a demo, the button toggles between the two data arrays:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var toggle = false;

var data1 = [{
  "state": "California",
  "values": 50
}, {
  "state": "Massachusetts",
  "values": 20
}, {
  "state": "Texas",
  "values": 15
}, {
  "state": "New York",
  "values": 5
}, {
  "state": "Washington",
  "values": 1
}];

var data2 = [{
  "state": "Massachusetts",
  "values": 70
}, {
  "state": "California",
  "values": 40
}, {
  "state": "New York",
  "values": 20
}, {
  "state": "Washington",
  "values": 15
}, {
  "state": "Texas",
  "values": 10
}];

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([30, 370])
  .domain(data1.map(d => d.state))
  .padding(0.2);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([120, 10])
  .domain([0, d3.max(data1, d => d.values)]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "xAxis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,120)")
  .call(xAxis);

var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "yAxis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)")
  .call(yAxis);

var span = d3.select("span");

span.text("Data: data1")

draw(data1)

function draw(data) {

  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.values)]);

  var rects = svg.selectAll(".rects")
    .data(data, d => d.state);

  rects.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .merge(rects)
    .attr("x", d => xScale(d.state))
    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("y", d => yScale(d.values))
    .attr("height", d => 120 - yScale(d.values))
    .attr("fill", "teal")
    .attr("class", "rects");

  gY.call(yAxis)

}

d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
  if (toggle) {
    draw(data1);
    span.text("Data: data1")
  } else {
    draw(data2);
    span.text("Data: data2")
  };
  toggle = !toggle;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<span></span>
<br>
<svg width="400">
</svg>
```